# Latest upgrade 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, updates

This morning I selected a routine update to the system following which the system has crashed completely. The best I can achieve now is the grub prompt.

Is there a way to reverse this state of affairs?

Comment: Can you boot with older kernel(s) from "advanced options for ubuntu"?

Comment: @pomsky Yes, thank you. I selected an earlier version of the kernel and that has now let me successfully boot into Ubuntu. Where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same for 16.04.
Revert back to 4.4.0-104 and purge the -108 update using Ubuntu Recovery mode. Will require a few reboots to fix this.

Comment: And the steps are what?